# How to auto approve console request on Jenkins

Tags: windows, github, jenkins, ssh, cmd

I'm doing a integration with jenkins and github, and after it compiles the project i want to push the .exe file to github.

I already did the configurarions of SSH on my console (i'm using windows with putty to manage the ssh keys)

but when the jenkins will run the post build console command it returns me this :

> If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
>   PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
>   If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
>   If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
>   connection.

and still in this message for ever i want to know how o do approve this message when jenkins request this.

Comment: my keys are already on the regedit, but for some reason jenkins is requesting for press Y and i don't know how to press manually Y once that he only shows me the log console.

Comment: yes they are look http://puu.sh/mvXO6.png

Comment: Jenkins is running on my user theres no special account or configuration that i have done. Theres anything that i have to do ?

Comment: Yeah he really was logged as System, but now is returning this on Jenkins Console Output
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Comment: Not sure about that one. Maybe another question is in order. Maybe even on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logged in as the user that Jenkins runs as, use putty to manually connect to the destination and accept the request to put the key in putty's cache. If Jenkins is running as a service, go to Services and check the "Log On" tab in the Properties dialog to see who it's running as.

If you want to add the key to putty's cache manually, the key is mentioned in [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/197489/where-does-putty-store-known-hosts-information-on-windows).